# top reports extremely high cpu-used time for all processes

Tags: linux, server-crashes

The server was up for less than 10 mins, but top shows extremely high cpu-used time for all process[1] (more than million hours used), this is a 24 core machine. System eventually crashed in 10-15 mins. It came back to normal after power recycle.

I'm leaning towards a faulty hardware that somehow got correctly initialized by power recycle.

Any idea what could have gone wrong ?

[1]

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                              
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S 100.0  0.0  30019,26 ksoftirqd/2
   33 root      20   0     0    0    0 S 100.0  0.0  40025,54 ksoftirqd/7
   53 root      20   0     0    0    0 S 100.0  0.0  65042,06 ksoftirqd/12
 2842 root      20   0 14.0g 362m  11m S 5500.0  0.3  8206270h java
12830 root      20   0  104m 2400 1532 S 100.0  0.0  5139288h bash
 2541 root      39  19     0    0    0 S  1.0  0.0 300194:24 kipmi0
14937 root      20   0 13516 1640  956 R  0.7  0.0   0:00.12 top
  160 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0  20012,57 kblockd/6
    1 root      20   0 21444 1548 1240 S  0.0  0.0  4270563h init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 785508,31 kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 10237405h ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R  0.0  0.0 300194:20 migration/1
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  30019,26 ksoftirqd/1
   10 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R  0.0  0.0 300194:20 watchdog/1
   11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2
   12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2
   14 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 300194:20 watchdog/2
   15 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3
   16 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 900583:01 ksoftirqd/3
   18 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 300194:20 watchdog/
```